# Results from SQL Query not getting passed to resolve() in Node Js Promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I thought I was doing this right, but I guess not. I am trying to pass the results from the query to the function in `then()`. I have a `console.log()` logging results from inside the two functions. The first one spits out the results as it should. The second one is giving me `undefined` and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    var dbConnect = () => new Promise(
        (res, rej) => {

            var connection = mysql.createPool(Config.mariaDBCred);

            connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {

                if(err) return rej(err);
                return res(connection);

            });


        }
    );

    var dbQuery = (connection, queryString, paramArray) => new Promise(
        (res, rej) => {

            var sql = mysql.format(queryString, paramArray);

            connection.query(sql,
                (err, results, fields) => {

                    connection.release();

                    console.log(results); //THIS DISPLAYS RESULTS FROM THE QUERY CORRECTLY
                    if(err) return rej(err);
                    return res(results, fields);

                }
            );

        }
    );


    //CHECK IF EMAIL EXISTS
    module.exports.doesEmailExist = (email, callback) => {

        dbConnect().then(
            (connection) => {
                dbQuery(
                    connection,
                    'SELECT `id`, `password_hash` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?',
                    [email]
                )
            }
        ).then(
            (results, fields) => {
                console.log(results); //THIS DISPLAY UNDEFINED
                if(results.length > 0) return callback(true, results);
                return callback(false, "Email does not exist.");
            }
        ).catch(
            (reason) => {
                console.log(reason);
                return callback(false, "Internal Error");
            }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Wait... do i need to put the second`then()` inside the first `then()`? But if that's the case, then how do I avoid using two catches?

Comment: nope, but this means that your first `then` isn't working properly, try removing the backtick from your query `( select id, password ...  from users ...)`

Comment: @Taki unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the edits below will resolve all of your issues, but in terms of your problems with regards to the `Promise` API, they should steer you in the right direction.

First, in the `dbQuery` function, I resolve an object because you can only resolve a single value in a promise.

Second, to chain promises, you must return promises. In your first `then` handler you weren't returning the `Promise` from `dbQuery` (after `dbConnect`).

Finally, I changed your second `then` handler to work with the single resolved object, rather than the multiple parameters used previously. Before, had everything worked, `results` would have been defined, but not `fields`. It's good practice to resolve an `Array` or an `Object` in cases like these. If your using es6, object/array destructuring makes ease of this.

Another note. If you are using Promises, consider ditching the callback pattern implemented in your `doesEmailExist` function, if not altogether. It's more consistent, and you won't have to wrap `catch` handlers, unless targeting specific error cases. Food for thought.

```
var dbConnect = () => new Promise(
     (res, rej) => {

         var connection = mysql.createPool(Config.mariaDBCred);

         connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {

             if(err) return rej(err);
             return res(connection);

         });


     }
 );

 var dbQuery = (connection, queryString, paramArray) => new Promise(
     (res, rej) => {

         var sql = mysql.format(queryString, paramArray);

         connection.query(sql,
             (err, results, fields) => {

                 connection.release();

                 console.log(results); //THIS DISPLAYS RESULTS FROM THE QUERY CORRECTLY
                 if(err) return rej(err);
                 // return res(results, fields); NOPE, can only resolve one argu
                 return res({ results: results, fields: fields }) // resolve an object

             }
         );

     }
 );


 //CHECK IF EMAIL EXISTS
 module.exports.doesEmailExist = (email, callback) => {

     dbConnect().then(
         (connection) => {
            // Return the promise from `dbQuery` call
             return dbQuery(
                 connection,
                 'SELECT `id`, `password_hash` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?',
                 [email]
             )
         }
     ).then(
         (response) => {
            // Can only resolve one argument
            var results = response.results;
            var fields = response.fields;
             console.log(results); //THIS DISPLAY UNDEFINED
             if(results.length > 0) return callback(true, results);
             return callback(false, "Email does not exist.");
         }
     ).catch(
         (reason) => {
             console.log(reason);
             return callback(false, "Internal Error");
         }
     );

 }
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this insight. I'm really trying to grasp the concept of promises. I want to get rid of the `callback()` and convert everything to Promises. Just kind of doing it one step at a time. Going to try this now.

Comment: You're welcome! Once you get the hang of it, you won't go back to callbacks, event if you could! Especially considering the `async/await` features of es7

Comment: Well that definitely solved that issue. Thank You so much. Now I just need to figure out why the functions that call `doesEmailExist()` continue to execute even when a user exists. lol.